# Cassandra RPC_TIMEOUT Error by using [cqlsh 4.1.0 | Cassandra 2.0.3 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.38.0]

Tags: cassandra

We were running couple of python scripts, which is internally reading/writing/deleting on couple of tables and we had set up Cassandra two node cluster which is basically AWS instance storage, unfortunately sometimes we were getting RPC_TIMEOUT ERROR like `cql.apivalues.OperationalError: Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.`
We were trying to reproduce the same error with single table and executing python script which is internally calling the 15 threads, will do Read and Write operations on single table. In between we were getting RPC_TIMEOUT ERROR on console. Please find the below message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Test.py", line 136, in <module>
response = controller.get(get_all_dict)
File "Test.py", line 47, in get
data_entity_pk_list = dal.fetch_all_pks(data_entity_obj)
File "/home/qa_integration/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherry/dal/dal.py", line 203, in fetch_all_pks
cursor.execute(CQLString)
File "/home/qa_integration/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cql/cursor.py", line 80, in execute
response = self.get_response(prepared_q, cl)
File "/home/qa_integration/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cql/thrifteries.py", line 77, in get_response
return self.handle_cql_execution_errors(doquery, compressed_q, compress, cl)
File "/home/qa_integration/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cql/thrifteries.py", line 105, in handle_cql_execution_errors
raise cql.OperationalError("Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.")
cql.apivalues.OperationalError: Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.
```

We had set up single node cluster for Cassandra instance storage,
   We were trying to find out the related error messages from system.log and cassandra.log files.
   Unfortunately there is no error messages, for this we had changed log4j-server.properties files by
   Passing DEBUG and ERROR.
   Even no luck.  Could anybody please let us know the permanent solution for RPC_TIMEOUT error?

Please find the below keyspace and table structure.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE fsnhpdb WITH replication = {
'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
'replication_factor': '1'
};
USE fsnhpdb;
CREATE TABLE fs_site (
  rkey text,
  ckey text,
  body text,
  ikey text,
  PRIMARY KEY (rkey, ckey)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
CREATE INDEX fs_site_index ON fs_site (ckey);
CREATE INDEX fs_site_index_ikey ON fs_site (ikey);
```

Regards,
Ashok.

Comment: What query do you execute? Are you truing to retrieve the data for a large number (all?) of primary keys?

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I am trying to execute select * from fs_site; and it has 1 lakh records, i think there no problem with data, cassandra is column oriented data base , it will be fetching on column keys right.

Comment: You generally should avoid queries like ``select * from <table>``, i.e. without restricting your partition (primary) key either by ``=`` or by ``IN``. Those unrestricted queries will have poor performance when the number of keys/rows is high.

Comment: hi Mikhail, I am agree your point, but in actual workflow we are passing primary by = operator. basically it will fetch 1 or 2 records. even though some times we are getting RPC_TIMEOUT Error.what is the permanent solution for this.

Comment: hi @Ashok. Take a look at ``TRACING`` for you queries